# "Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters" in Python

Tags: python

I was trying to solve this problem from Leetcode:

> Given a string, find the length of the longest substring without
>   repeating characters.
>
> Examples:
>
> Given "abcabcbb", the answer is "abc", which the length is 3.
>
> Given "bbbbb", the answer is "b", with the length of 1.
>
> Given "pwwkew", the answer is "wke", with the length of 3. Note that
>   the answer must be a substring, "pwke" is a subsequence and not a
>   substring.

I would like to get some code review for the following solution:

```
class Solution:
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s):
      dict = {}
      start, end, curr_length, max_length = 0, 0, 0, 0
      while ( end < len(s)):
        char = s[end]

        if char not in dict:
            curr_length += 1
        else: 
            start = max(dict[char], start)

        max_length = max(max_length, end - start + 1)
        dict[char] = end + 1
        end += 1
      return max_length

"""
    my logic is that
    * 1) Initialize a hashmap/dictionary/object that will map characters to their index.
    * 2) Initialize `start`, `end`, and `answer`
    * 3) Loop through the string while `end` is less than `length` of string
    * 4) Check if character at `end` is in hashmap
      * a) If so, repeating character exists between `start` and `end`. Set `start` to be the `max_length` between the value of character in the hashmap, and `start`

"""
```

And it passes all of the leetcode tests.

Answer (score 7):

Nice solution, please find a few thoughts below:

1. Do you need to wrap it in class for leetcode? It's unnecessary otherwise.
2. Function names use `snake_case` and not `camelCase`, check [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more details. Hence it would be `length_of_longest_substring`.
3. Do not use `dict` as a variable name, it is already built-in to construct dictionaries.
4. I think a for-loop would be preferable over a while-loop in this case, it's more straightforward, less clunky, and easier to understand.
5. You update `curr_length`, but never actually use it to determine your `max_length`.
6. The docstring should come right after the `class Solution` and before the first function, and no line should be longer than 79 characters. Moreover, you seem to not have pasted the entire docstrings, it just ends mid-sentence.

Answer (score 3):

#### Minor technical issues

There are a couple of minor technical issues with the solution:

- When looping over an iterable, if you need both the index and the value of the current item, it's good to use `enumerate`, so that you cannot accidentally forget to increment the loop counter, and syntax is nicely compact yet readable.
- `curr_length` is modified but never used: should be removed.
- The code is most readable when there is one statement per line. So I recommend to split multi-assignments like `start, end, curr_length, max_length = 0, 0, 0, 0`. Simple multi-assignments with 2 terms are usually ok though, for example `left, right = ...` when implementing a binary search
- The parentheses are unnecessary around the condition in `while end < len(s):`
- It's unfortunate use names that are types in many languages, such as `dict` and `char`
- PEP8 recommends to indent with 4 spaces. And it strongly recommends to use the same indent width consistently. (The posted code indents the class body by 4 spaces, but everything else with 2.)

#### Alternative implementation

Putting the above tips together, and throwing in some [doctests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html):

```
class Solution(object):
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s):
        """
        >>> Solution().lengthOfLongestSubstring("bpfbhmipx")
        7

        >>> Solution().lengthOfLongestSubstring("abcabcbb")
        3

        >>> Solution().lengthOfLongestSubstring("bbbbb")
        1

        >>> Solution().lengthOfLongestSubstring("pwwkew")
        3

        >>> Solution().lengthOfLongestSubstring("tmmzuxt")
        5

        >>> Solution().lengthOfLongestSubstring("a")
        1

        >>> Solution().lengthOfLongestSubstring("")
        0

        >>> Solution().lengthOfLongestSubstring("abc")
        3

        """

        longest = 0
        start = -1
        last = {}

        for i, c in enumerate(s):
            if c in last:
                start = max(start, last[c])
            longest = max(longest, i - start)
            last[c] = i

        return longest
```

Answer (score 2):

just a note, for string iteration, a for loop might be more suitable

from

```
  while ( end < len(s)):
    char = s[end]
    ...
    end += 1
```

to

```
for end, char in enumerate(s)
    ...
```

Comment: @Mathias Ettinger edited